# Postgres PK index not honored if data added before PK is set?

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing, foreign-keys

We're working with Postgres 9.4; we have some developers who have created tables without primary keys, and have gone in after data is in the tables and created the PKs. What we see with an "explain analyze" is that the implicit index is not used on queries against these tables when there's a small amount of data in them (in this case, 15 rows).

In particular, if you create a table this way, and load it with some data:

```
drop table if exists A;

CREATE TABLE A (
    id integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT into A values (21200), (21300), (21301), (21251), (21202), (21203), (21252), (21253), (21302), (21254), (21255), (21304), (21305), (21204), (21755);

ALTER TABLE ONLY A ADD CONSTRAINT A_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Follow this up with an explain analyze:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
select * from A where id=21200;
```

and you see that a table scan is the result.

```
"Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..1.19 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (id = 21200)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 14"
"Planning time: 0.327 ms"
"Execution time: 0.031 ms"
```

If the primary key had been added prior to any data being added, then you would see an index scan.

So my question is ... why the difference? Given it's a small table, the table scan probably isn't costing me anything, really, but ... why 2 identical tables, constructed through a slightly different process, produce different results (index scan vs. table scan)?

Comment: Did some testing and got same result as you describe. No idea why is happening .

Comment: If you add the primary key either on the `CREATE TABLE` or using the `ALTER TABLE` before the `INSERT INTO` explain will use the index.

Comment: Correct ... but the original dev didn't. It's a weird result that the 2 tables, in the end, are identical but postgres chooses the index for one, but not for the other.

Comment: Further testing. If you add 1 million rows doesnt matter if you add the PK before of after. EXPLAIN use the index. So looks like data size is a factor

Comment: For a table with only 15 rows Postgres will never use an index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I thought the same. But if you create the primary key before insert postgres use the index. That is why I think is interesting.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OotTK.png

Comment: An `analyze` will probably change that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What you mean? I try with/without  analyze and get same result.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm guessing @a_horse_with_no_name is talking about `VACUUM ANALYZE`, not `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Comment: I've tried vacuum analyze without any difference. The explain analyze still indicates a table scan for the one table ... index lookup for the other. Granted, for 15 rows I'm not worried about it, but it's very puzzling why the engine picks 2 different ways for the 2 tables (even cleared statistics w/same result).

Comment: If the implementation doesn't need its embodiment of the index then isn't it doing you a favour by not creating it yet? Eg see "ALTER TABLE SET storage_parameter = value" documentation for [9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html) & [9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html)--the implemenation doesn't necessarily immediately reorganize.